# Why is my first query in Laravel always longer than the rest?

Tags: mysql, laravel, performance

Using Laravel 8 with a Mysql database, the first query when a page loads takes significantly longer to run than all following queries.

[image]

Even when I set the session drive to file to remove that query, the query that only took 59ms before, now takes 302ms when it is the first query.

[image]

I get the same result both on my localhost server and on my AWS web server (both use the same AWS hosted database)

Comment: The profiler is probably doing something wrong or not taking the application's bootstrapping into account.  Laravel is probably doing some things when the page load that take about 250~260ms.

Comment: @IGP how would I track down what those things are?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. Also keep in mind the debugbar itself will make the site run slower. Perhaps it's got something to do with it? If you want to know for sure you could ask this question in the laravel-debugbar issues on github

Comment: Perhaps "connecting", filing up caches, etc.  Can you provide the queries being performed?

Comment: @RickJames the queries are provided in the screenshots. Or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

Is `id`  the `PRIMARY KEY` of each table?

```
products:  INDEX(category, year_end)
orders:  INDEX(session_id, building)
```

If adding those indexes does not help the timings, I will dig in a different direction.

Note:  The indexes are likely to help speed, not "the first query", as per your Question.

Physically, where is Laravl located?  Where is the database located?  I smells like they are a few thousand miles (km) apart.  Note how most queries take about 60ms, and the first takes about 5 times that.  I wonder if Laravel is doing 5 queries for the first one?  And the two servers are about 50ms apart.  This leaves about 10ms for the actual query, which seems more likely.

Comment: Sessions and orders primary key is id, products is part_number - all are set as indexes.

Comment: I am not able to add the `INDEX` to products, the year_end attribute is a relationship on a different table.

Both AWS RDS (database) and EC2 (Laravel) are on the us-west-2 (Oregon) region. For local development, I am running out of California to the RDS database.

Comment: CA to OR is less than 60ms, so distance is only part of the answer.  How big are the tables?

Comment: products is ~4100 records at 3.5M
orders currently has 3 records in it at 32K